# Webpack loader isn't called with sass local imports

Tags: webpack, sass, loader, webpack-plugin, webpack-loader

I'm working on a webpack loader that should modify the content of a sass file in some way. the issue is that this loader isn't being called except when I import the sass file within JS so

✅ This will trigger a loader call

File.js

```
import 'file.scss';
```

❌ This won't trigger the loader

File.scss

```
@import './file';
```

does Sass-loader handle those imports internally & is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do, maybe with plugins?

**Note:-** the modification should be done while the module is being imported because I'm going to pass a query string like this one

```
@import './file?doTheModification=true';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that webpack only handle the first level import(the import within the JS file) and any @import within the sass files is handled within the sass compiler itself but it does use webpack's file resolver module