# Import scss file from less using webpack5 custom loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass, less

I followed [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aliustaoglu/a4c5b5f035e996823cc6335ebe0d0ee5) suggestions for importing scss via custom js loader, But I ran into problem - The custom loader does not run for the imported scss file from less.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/scss/ant.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[6].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[6].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[6].use[3]!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[6].use[4]!./src/app/scss/ant.less)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):
```

I'm using:

- "webpack": "^5.72.0"
- "less": "^4.1.2"
- "less-loader": "^10.2.0"
- "sass": "^1.50.1"
- "sass-loader": "^12.6.0"

Here is the relevant module section of my webpack config (after ejecting):

```
module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        // ... Rule for Handle node_modules packages that contain sourcemaps
        {
          oneOf: [
            // Rule for handle `image/avif` 
            ...
            // Rule for handle [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/] assets
            ...
            // Rule for handle /\.svg$/ assets
            ...
            // Rule for custom formatJs transformer
            ...
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            ...
            // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
            // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
            ...
            // Include less-loader (exact settings may deviate depending on your building/bundling procedure)
            {
              test: lessRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                  lessOptions: {
                    javascriptEnabled: true,
                  },
                },
                "less-loader"
              ),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
            ...
            // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
            // using the extension .module.css
            ...
            // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
            // By default we support SASS Modules with the
            // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: [sassModuleRegex, lessRegex],
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                  modules: {
                    mode: 'icss',
                  },
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
            // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              exclude: lessRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                  modules: {
                    mode: 'local',
                    getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                  },
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
            },
            // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
            // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
            // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
            // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
            // that fall through the other loaders.
            {
              // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpacks internal loaders.
              exclude: [/^$/, /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
            // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
          ],
        },
        // Define a second rule for only being used from less files
        // This rule will only be used for converting our sass-variables to less-variables
        {
          test: sassRegex,
          issuer: lessRegex,
          use: {
            loader: path.resolve(
              paths.appSrc,
              'app/scss/sassVarsToLess.js' // I ensured it is the correct path
            ),
          }
        },
      ].filter(Boolean),
    }
```

'app/scss/sassVarsToLess.js':

```js
"use strict";

// This loader will simply replace all $something sass-variable with @something less-variables
export default function (source) {
  return source.replace(/\$/gi, "@");
}
```

The printed error indicates that the sassVarsToLess.js file does not loads the imported scss from less. I tried to change the loaders order - but it doesn't work in any other order.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66827210/webpack-loader-isnt-called-with-sass-local-imports). When transpiling SASS or SCSS, all imports below the topmost level seem to be handled by the SASS transpiler, not webpack.
Maybe the same is true for LESS.